# Why is DIV pushed below instead of to the side?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a 'slide-out' div that slides out when out hover over it. What I want to happen is that I want the left div to push the right div off into oblivion, but not below the div, but to the right.
Does anyone know why this happens?

Here is my script:

```
.container {
    width: 796px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left {
    display:none;
    float: left;
    width: 256px;
    background: green;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 796px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

[Here is a live demo](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/demo2/)
click 'colorbox', then 'show left div'.

Thank you everyone! :))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `.left` and `.right` are within `.container` the reason one gets pushed down is because there is not enough space.

You have set a `width:796px` for the `.container` and so the children i.e. `.left` and `.right` would need to add up to `796px`. At the moment they add up to `1052px` and so one of them is pushed down as they cannot fit side by side.

**EDIT :** Using inner container method mentioned in my comments below and in @Matteo's answer you need to adjust the following css.

```
.inner_container{
    width: 1396px; /* changed from 1052px */
}
.right {
    background-color: red;
    float: left; /* changed from right */
    height: 100%;
    width: 796px;
}
```

The reason it needs to be `1396px` is because it needs to be large enough that when `.left` is expanded to `600px` that `.right` at `769px` can still fit beside it. Then changing to `float:left` is necessary so that there is no gap between the `.left` and `.right` and it remains visible when it is pushed sideways.

Comment: I don't want the container to 'enlarge', but for the right column to sort of go under the outside of the container. Do you get what I mean? This is why I tried overflow:hidden.

Comment: @pufAmuf: You could set a fixed height for `.container` and make `.left` and `.right` the same fixed height. That way when one is pushed below the other it will be beneath the edges of `.container` and so will not be visible as you have `overflow:hidden` set. Or if the height will vary, you can use an inner container that is wide enough to hold both `.left` and `.right`, again the overflow will be hidden.

Comment: Thank you tw16. I updated the online link with the new code and notice that the right div still goes below the left div, when it should go off the screen.

Comment: @pufAmuf: You haven't made the changes I suggested. You haven't changed the width of `.inner_container` to `1396px` nor have you changed `.right` to `float:left`.

Comment: Sorry tw16, my brain isn't working anymore today. It works!! :) thank you so much :))

Answer (score 1):

Add another div inside `.container` which is wide enough to hold `.left` and `.right`.

http://jsfiddle.net/DRnRQ/

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 796px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 256px;
    background: green;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 796px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.inner_container {
    width: 1052px;
}
```

MARKUP:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner_container">
        <div class="left">a</div>
        <div class="right">b</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to work. Thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: let me make changes on the public version :)

Comment: Try checking the link I have in my post now

Comment: There's some javascript changing the width of `.container` when you click the button. Other than that it looks fine with `.left` on the left and `.right` on the right.

Comment: Hi Matteo, yes there is. The point is that the div on the left is hidden until the button is pressed. When you do that, the whole container enlarges and the left div pops up. Inside that div there will be information that isn't completely visible unless you hover over it. When you do hover over it, the left div widens, effecively pushing the right div off to the side. The right div overflows from the container itself, but since overflow:hidden, the part that's outside the container will not be visible :)

Comment: @pufAmuf: Do you wan't `.right` to be partially visible or totally hidden when `.left` is hovered?

Comment: I would like .right to be partially visible when .left is hovered please :). Only a piece of .right that goes outside the modal will be invisible.